# How can I make this query easier to read

Tags: mysql

I have a massive query below, the things I don't like are:

- I can't reference item_tax_percent_regular and item_tax_percent_cumulative as alias inside the query. (I have to repeat the massive sum statement whenever I want to use them)
- IT IS JUST BIG

The query does exactly what I want, but it is so big.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE phppos_sales_items_temp (SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted, date(sale_time) as sale_date, phppos_sales_items.sale_id, comment,payment_type, customer_id, employee_id, phppos_items.item_id, NULL as item_kit_id, supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_cost_price, item_unit_price, category, 

SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END) as item_tax_percent_regular, 
SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative = 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END) as item_tax_percent_cumulative, discount_percent, 
(item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) as subtotal, phppos_sales_items.line as line, serialnumber, phppos_sales_items.description as description, 
ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)+ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) +((ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) + (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)) *(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative = 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END))/100),2) as total, 

ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) +((ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) + (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)) *(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative = 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END))/100) as tax, 

(item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) - (item_cost_price*quantity_purchased) as profit FROM phppos_sales_items INNER JOIN phppos_sales ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id=phppos_sales.sale_id INNER JOIN phppos_items ON phppos_sales_items.item_id=phppos_items.item_id 

LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_suppliers ON phppos_items.supplier_id=phppos_suppliers.person_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id=phppos_sales_items_taxes.sale_id and phppos_sales_items.item_id=phppos_sales_items_taxes.item_id and phppos_sales_items.line=phppos_sales_items_taxes.line
WHERE date(sale_time) BETWEEN "2011-07-28" and "2011-07-28" 
GROUP BY sale_id, item_id, line) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted, date(sale_time) as sale_date, phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id, comment,payment_type, customer_id, employee_id, NULL as item_id, phppos_item_kits.item_kit_id, '' as supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_kit_cost_price, item_kit_unit_price, category, 
SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END) as item_kit_tax_percent_regular, SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative = 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END) as item_kit_tax_percent_cumulative, discount_percent, (item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) as subtotal,
phppos_sales_item_kits.line as line, '' as serialnumber, phppos_sales_item_kits.description as description, ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)+ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) +((ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) + (item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)) *(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative = 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END))/100),2) as total,

 ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) +((ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative != 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END)/100),2) + (item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)) *(SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative = 1 THEN percent ELSE 0 END))/100) as tax, 

(item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) - (item_kit_cost_price*quantity_purchased) as profit FROM phppos_sales_item_kits 
INNER JOIN phppos_sales ON phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id=phppos_sales.sale_id INNER JOIN phppos_item_kits ON phppos_sales_item_kits.item_kit_id=phppos_item_kits.item_kit_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes ON phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id=phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.sale_id and phppos_sales_item_kits.item_kit_id=phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.item_kit_id and phppos_sales_item_kits.line=phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.line WHERE date(sale_time) 
BETWEEN "2011-07-28" and "2011-07-28" 
GROUP BY sale_id, item_kit_id, line) ORDER BY sale_id, line
```

Comment: Definitely line breaks and indentations.

Comment: A simple solution to get you started would be to drop your SQL into a beautifer. e.g. http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "as" to create aliases:

```
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes AS sikTaxes ON sikTaxes.sale_id=phppos_sales.sale_id
...
```

You can use the aliases you create throughout the query.

Yanking out some of the arithmetic into user defined functions might also help.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  I've incorporated some line break formatting to assist.  I put the operator on the next line (e.g. comma separation or subtraction) for easy commenting:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE phppos_sales_items_temp
(
SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted
, date(sale_time) as sale_date
, phppos_sales_items.sale_id
, comment
, payment_type
, customer_id
, employee_id
, phppos_items.item_id
, NULL as item_kit_id
, supplier_id
, quantity_purchased
, item_cost_price
, item_unit_price
, category
, SUM(CASE
     WHEN cumulative != 1
     THEN percent
     ELSE 0
     END) as item_tax_percent_regular
, SUM(CASE
     WHEN cumulative = 1
     THEN percent
     ELSE 0
     END) as item_tax_percent_cumulative
, discount_percent
, (item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100) as subtotal
, phppos_sales_items.line as line
, serialnumber
, phppos_sales_items.description as description
, ROUND((item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  + ROUND((item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  + (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + ((ROUND((item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + (item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100))
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative = 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END)) / 100), 2) as total
, ROUND((item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + ((ROUND((item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent/100)
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + (item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100))
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative = 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END)) / 100) as tax
, (item_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  - (item_cost_price * quantity_purchased) as profit
FROM phppos_sales_items
INNER JOIN phppos_sales ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id = phppos_sales.sale_id
INNER JOIN phppos_items ON phppos_sales_items.item_id = phppos_items.item_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_suppliers
   ON phppos_items.supplier_id = phppos_suppliers.person_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes
   ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id = phppos_sales_items_taxes.sale_id
   AND phppos_sales_items.item_id = phppos_sales_items_taxes.item_id
   AND phppos_sales_items.line = phppos_sales_items_taxes.line
WHERE date(sale_time) BETWEEN "2011-07-28" and "2011-07-28" 
GROUP BY sale_id
, item_id
, line
) 

UNION ALL

(
SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted
, date(sale_time) as sale_date
, phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id
, comment
, payment_type
, customer_id
, employee_id
, NULL as item_id
, phppos_item_kits.item_kit_id
, '' as supplier_id
, quantity_purchased
, item_kit_cost_price
, item_kit_unit_price
, category
, SUM(CASE
     WHEN cumulative != 1
     THEN percent
     ELSE 0
     END) as item_kit_tax_percent_regular
, SUM(CASE
     WHEN cumulative = 1
     THEN percent
     ELSE 0
     END) as item_kit_tax_percent_cumulative
, discount_percent
, (item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100) as subtotal
, phppos_sales_item_kits.line as line
, '' as serialnumber
, phppos_sales_item_kits.description as description
, ROUND((item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  + ROUND((item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + ((ROUND((item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + (item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100))
  * (SUM(CASE WHEN
        cumulative = 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END)) / 100), 2) as total
, ROUND((item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  * (SUM(CASE
     WHEN cumulative != 1
     THEN percent
     ELSE 0
     END) / 100), 2)
  + ((ROUND((item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative != 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END) / 100), 2)
  + (item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100))
  * (SUM(CASE
        WHEN cumulative = 1
        THEN percent
        ELSE 0
        END)) / 100) as tax
, (item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased - item_kit_unit_price * quantity_purchased * discount_percent / 100)
  - (item_kit_cost_price * quantity_purchased) as profit
FROM phppos_sales_item_kits 
INNER JOIN phppos_sales
   ON phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id = phppos_sales.sale_id
INNER JOIN phppos_item_kits
   ON phppos_sales_item_kits.item_kit_id = phppos_item_kits.item_kit_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes
   ON phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id = phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.sale_id
   AND phppos_sales_item_kits.item_kit_id = phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.item_kit_id
   AND phppos_sales_item_kits.line = phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.line
WHERE date(sale_time) BETWEEN "2011-07-28" and "2011-07-28" 
GROUP BY sale_id
, item_kit_id
, line
)
ORDER BY sale_id
, line
```

Comment: When I continue a statement across multiple line I always like to end a line with something incomplete so that readers will look to the next line.  An operator or comma will do, or "inner join" with the target on the next line.

Comment: Indenting accomplishes that.  Commenting the last line in a list will leave a dangling comma causing the query to fail, so I tend to put them at the front.